# Beating A casino Mathematically

Tags: probability

tomorrow I will be going to a casino and I'm looking for any mathematically proven and applicable strategies that give me good odds at winning.

Givens: I have at most 500 dollars I am willing to spend/lose. Either I win at least 100 dollars or I loose it all.

Example of none applicable strategy:

The Martingale Strategy states that given a fair roulette $50/50$ odds. I could apply the following. Make an initial bet $1$ and keep doubling the amount of money I bet. If done enough times I will eventually win and make a total profit of $1$. However when it comes to the application aspect this is poorly applicable. Assuming I loose $k$ times then my total loss will be $2^{k} -1$. Assuming I win the next time, I will have accumulated a total of 1 dollar for my troubles. I could also make my initial bet higher, thus receive more money back. However, as this formula is exponential I may run out of money pretty soon if I make my initial bet 100. Furthermore, if I wanted to double my money (100 usd) by getting 1 pound every time until I have 200, the probability will be no greater than  $1/e$. Thus, I have better odds just betting all my money all ounce.

Alternate option: Would blackjack or any card game be better if I can count the cards and such.

Note: after I come back from my trip. I will update this post on how it went most likely Monday /14/21

Comment: Good luck, you'll need it.

Comment: Never play the house. If you know how to play poker well, play intoxicated people who are there just to have fun.

Comment: Please note that to my knowledge, casinos frown on people counting cards (or looking like they’re counting cards), so it may not be a good idea to try that out. (Also note that if there were a strategy that gave you good odds to win some money, written on such a public forum, the casinos would find that out and adjust their games accordingly).

Comment: Have a couple whiskies with you. That way you forget about the money you lost. Martingale strats are not the way to go. There is also no real way to beat probability.

Answer (score 5):

All of the games at casinos are designed to favor the house. So no matter what game you play the expected value of return is less than zero. This means after a few games, it is possible to seem to consistently win or consistently lose, but over time, the more plays will eventually have you slowly losing more. This is a direct application of the law of large numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I work at a casino and have delve into the maths. The martingale strategies and it's derivatives definelty aren't a winning strategy. And it isn't just the size of your bankroll limiting you, but for tables games like roulette, they have minimum and maximum limits. Usually, you'll only be able to double your bet 7 or 8 times.

For counting cards, it depends on location. Casinos (where I am from (Australia)) use 8 desks of cards for blackjack and automatic card shufflers. Additionally, if you were able to, it's easy to spot a card counter.

The fairest game you'll find is commission Bacarrat a true 50/50 (except you pay commission).

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about the operation of Casinos, only Mathematics; but I thought I would add that the chances of finding a working strategy that would put the odds in your favour in any Casino game is probably slim-to-none. I mean, it would depend on the game, the Casino's specific implementation of the game, and that's not to mention all the restrictions that the Casino has probably implemented to stop this happening. I mean, they probably pay people to try and find ways to exploit the games this way so they can patch them all up.

Honestly, your best bet (pun intended) is to just have fun and enjoy yourself. Don't spend anymore than you are willing to lose (know when to stop). That's what Casinos are for after all, they are not meant to give out free money. If finding a money making exploit in a Casino game was as easy as asking Stack Exchange, Casinos would have no money to give out!

Hope that helps a bit.